# How to breakup webpage text

Tags: python, web-scraping

I assume I have to use the /br to break up this text and extract the fixtures only, but cannot figure it out at all!

```
import requests
from termcolor import colored
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml.html as lh
import pandas as pd
import pprint
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen




# sample web page

sample_web_page = 'https://bleacherreport.com/articles/10005879-epl-schedule-2021-22-official-list-of-fixtures-for-new-premier-league-season'
  
# call get method to request that page
page = requests.get(sample_web_page)
# with the help of beautifulSoup and html parser create soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

z = soup.findAll('p', {'class':''})
print(z)
```

Comment: The site uses a backend api. You could edit the date of a url like this and get the data from JSON: https://statmilk.bleacherreport.com/api/scores/schedules?league=Soccer&date=2022-2-26&context=TN.227

Comment: Hi I see what youve done but not sure how to do, also I want to extract the data.  So how to?